# Saving deviceToken to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to save device token to `NSUserDefaults` but I couldn't do it.

**My code:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    var currentToken=preferences.stringForKey(pushTokenKey)
    if currentToken != deviceToken {
        var dataString = NSString(data: deviceToken, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String?
        self.preferences.setValue(dataString, forKey: pushTokenKey)
        self.preferences.synchronize()
    }
}
```

You can see i am comparing the tokens and if they are not same i am updating it. But it is always saving as `nil` I guess because `deviceToken` is `NSData`.

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Have a check deviceToken  for nil before comparing two tokens and since your is of optional types because you are doing optional casting, so deviceToken can be nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why you get nil is because it is not able to turn that NSData to NSString

By using `deviceToken.description` you will get the string token.

```
var currentToken=preferences.stringForKey(pushTokenKey)

if currentToken != deviceToken.description { // Here you were comparing  String and NSData ?? :S
    var dataString = deviceToken.description
    self.preferences.setValue(dataString, forKey: pushTokenKey)
    self.preferences.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: what should be done with the `description` of a push token? some server should parse that crap?

Comment: @Michael What do you mean? The description property is what you print out in println() which is a string.

Answer (score 3):

The device token should never be saved to anywhere. Just keep it in memory in some global variable. When you re-open the app, you will get the same token again from the APNS-API. Your delegate method will be called again, and the user will not be asked again if he already agreed to give you the token in the past. The documentation explicitely says that you should not save it!

The way your method works, you could also just save the token in any case, no matter if it changed or not, and it would do exactly the same, because the pattern is that

```
if(a != b) {
    b = a;
}
```

is equivalent to just

```
b = a;
```

Furthermore, the device token is binary data, so it is just not UTF-8 encoded (you tried to convert it to a string, interpreting the binary data as `NSUTF8StringEncoding`). In 99% of cases, it will not be possible to encode it as UTF-8, for this reason you get nil.

Furthermore, even if the token would be UTF-8 (which it will be in 1 out of 10^16 cases), the comparison will still say that they are not equal, because you are comparing an NSData binary with an NSString.

Comment: My algorithm: If token is changed then save it after that send to server. Is this wrong ? What should I do ? http://prntscr.com/7439ig

Comment: @TolgayToklar I would just send it to the server each time. The server then just saves it. Even the server does not need to check if it changed, it just needs the current value each time it wants to send a message. If you really want to save it, you may base64-encode it and compare that... Or save it to some file outside of NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure.Actually i was an android developer, in android we are checking the token and if changed we are sending to server for save.

Comment: So, what is the best way to do this ? I will do what you say ? :)

Comment: @TolgayToklar: your decision. you can also convert it to base64, and after that compare the new base64-encoded push token with the saved base64-encoded push token. If it changed, send it to the server and save the base64-encoded push token. i always sent the push token to the server. Because it's much easier, and the delegate method is usually only called once per app-start, so you have a request per day more on your server. If your app does 500 web-requests on average before it gets killed, you increase the server load by 0.2% by keeping the implementation simple...

Comment: @TolgayToklar: furthermore, you have to catch the case that you couldn't reach the server. in that case you have to re-send the token next time, even though it hasn't changed. So the user may complain that push doesn't work, and you can only tell them to uninstall the app and reinstall it. (with my method, you can tell them to kill the app and re-open it. of course this problem can be solved even more elegantly too.)